# Is there a way to migrate a Cloud9 instance to a regular EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9, aws-codestar

I have a Cloud9 EC2 instance running on Linux 2 AMI. The nice thing about the Cloud9 instance is that all the software packages I want (Rails) are installed and I didn't have to configure or install anything on the instance. Of course the instance shuts down when I'm not working in the environment. When I'm done developing, is there a way to migrate my development environment into a production environment? Or do I have to start a new EC2 instance, configure it (pain ITA), update it, lock it down, and download code from a repo? Or is there an AMI that is similar to what Cloud9 runs?

Comment: I tried creating an AMI from the EC2 running CLoud9. It shuts down also when not in use.

Comment: The answer might be to use GIthub for version control and deploy using an Elastic Beanstalk environment from the Github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though it greatly depends on what your definition of production means, and it's far from best practice to do so.

If all you want to do is prevent the EC2 instance that runs your C9 environment from shutting down, remove the `c9-automatic-shutdown` entry from `/etc/cron.d` and optionally run `restart cron`. For good measure you may wish to back up `~/.c9/stop-if-inactive.sh` and edit it to be a no-op.

I do have to reiterate making that one change is hardly making your C9/EC2 environment production ready. If you're looking for a batteries included way to create applications that are production ready, consider [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/?gclid=CjwKCAiAmZGrBhAnEiwAo9qHiZtGm2dZtG8N1LGp1UdvhYBgHX1K6lWaEeS1J-kateqBR4LReNtrURoCQAUQAvD_BwE&trk=9eb02e4d-80e0-4f27-a621-b90b3c870bf3&sc_channel=ps&ef_id=CjwKCAiAmZGrBhAnEiwAo9qHiZtGm2dZtG8N1LGp1UdvhYBgHX1K6lWaEeS1J-kateqBR4LReNtrURoCQAUQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!651751060764!e!!g!!aws%20amplify!19852662236!145019201417).